# Modify binary(1) column in SSMS grid

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Following is the error I get when I try to modify / insert `1` or `0` into a `binary(1)` column:

> Invalid value for cell (row 4, column 5).
>   
> The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid.
>   
> .Net Framework Data Type: Byte[]
>   
> Error Message: You cannot use the Result pane to set this Field data to values other than NULL.
>       Type a value appropriate for the data type or press ESC to cancel the change.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements to modify data, rather than using the grid from `Open Table` or `Edit Top N Rows`. It may seem slightly easier to work with the grid but there are all kinds of problems just waiting to happen. This is just one of many limitations you'll encounter...

Answer (score 7):

That is just the way it is for binary fields. You have to write an update statement to modify the value or an insert statement to add a row with a value.

If your column can have only the values 0 or 1 you should use a [`bit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) instead. `bit` columns can be modified directly in the edit grid in SQL Server Management Studio. `binary(1)` can hold the values `0x00` to `0xFF`.

From [Working with Data in the Results Pane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172022%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Values for columns with a binary data type will have NULL values by
>   default. These values can't be changed in the Results pane.

Comment: ...except if you're on an older version [and it still expects `true` and `false`, and returns an error with `0` or `1`](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/264592/ssms-deprecate-open-table).

Comment: Also this just emphasizes why we should all be using DML instead of some quirky grid that tries to treat our tables like spreadsheets.

Comment: Mikael Eriksson! Thanks! But it was not like this before and i Could RClick my Table and Click Edit Top 200 Rows and Inserted this succefully

Comment: @BlackViking That must have been some time ago. In SQL Server 2005 you get the same message and in SQL Server 2000 you get "Cannot edit this cell". Or perhaps the column used to a be a `bit` and it has been changed by someone to `binary(1)`?

Comment: i use sql server 2008 r2 and the column used to a be a Binary(1) and i Could Enter 1 or 0 to this but now .....

Comment: @BlackViking I think your memory is failing you. There is a big difference between `binary(1)` and `bit` - the former would have never accepted 0 or 1 as direct input in any grid that I've ever seen in Management Studio or Enterprise Manager.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Thanks!! now i change this to bit and try again to enter 0 or 1 or true or false at Edit Top 200 Rows but i see this error: Invalid value for cell (row 4, column 5).

The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid.
.Net Framework Data Type: Boolean
Error Message: You cannot use the Result pane to set this Field data to values other than NULL.

Type a value appropriate for the data type or press ESC to cancel the change.